# Textfield not displaying variable from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to get the data displayed from a database (it displays it on a dynamic page within a table) and have it as the value for a textfield on a different html page (map.html).

The value will be some sort of postcode/address and I want that to go into my google map page within the destination textfield. So when users check the location of the event they press the 'View on Map' button which will open up the page of the map and the data from the event should already be populated within the textfield.

However nothing appears and instead it remains blank, even when I just put in some dummy text it still doesn't populate. I know that the location value is being fetched as the alert correctly displays the location, but the problem is having it populate in the textfield.

I am using JQuery Mobile/Cordova/JavaScript/JQuery/HTML. The app is a one-page structure, with the exception of map.html which has it's own page.

Any ideas?

Fetching the location value:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btnMap", function(e){
    var location = $(this).data("rowlocation");
     viewMap(location);
 });
```

Snippet of Button:

```
<a data-rowlocation='" + response.rows.item(i).Location + "' href='map.html' onclick='viewMap(location)' data-role='button' rel='external' data-mini='true' class='btnMap'>View on Map</a></td></tr>"
```

viewMap Function:

```
function viewMap(location) {
alert(location);
$("#target-dest").val(location);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="target-dest" id="target-dest"  />
```

Comment: location is likely a reserved word - any console errors? Is the button type="button" if not make it one or add an `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: There has to be a problem with `#target-dest` because [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dtq9aap/) shows this working.

Comment: @Keeleon I have updated the code, so you can now see the button that triggers the function.

Comment: Please update your question with ALL important information such as the fact you are not showing your map on the same page as the link which makes it a completely different issue.

Comment: @mplungjan I've updated it a little, not much more to add to it. However, I have added the code in a jsfiddle session so you can see more of the code involved - https://jsfiddle.net/6kzt8hpe/1/

Comment: I do not see any updateEvent and I still do not know if you plan to open the map in a new page, also no mentioning of errors or lack thereof in the console

Comment: updateEvent has nothing to do with what I am trying to achieve, this function is working fine. I get no errors, with the code in jsfiddle, to which the map.html (which is the page that displays the map) is opens up fine, however nothing in the textfield is populated.  Here is an update of my original code - https://jsfiddle.net/mqL6058y/1/#&togetherjs=3BojUs3J6E

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way of passing the location to a new page - using your existing code would be to append the location as a query string to the href in the link.

```
 <a ...href='map.html?loc='" + response.rows.item(i).Location + "'...
```

and then on the destination page - use JS to grab the querystring from the URL, split it from the rest of the UURL and pass it to the textbox.

```
//js on destination page
var locn=location.href;
var locationPortions = locn.split("?loc=");
$('#target-dest").val(locationPortions[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy, let me give this ago and see if I can do it. If you do have time, I would appreciate if you could have a look at my other issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424120/when-returning-to-the-same-page-it-stops-scrolling

Comment: Ok, so i've just given this ago and still nothing is being populated within the textfield. I have put actual function into a jsfiddle session as well as the map.html code so you may able to identify the problem more easily - https://jsfiddle.net/6kzt8hpe/1/#&togetherjs=xvtxMAQyky

Answer (score 0):

Because the trigger for this is clicking an `<a>`, the link is causing a loading of the map.html page which negates the updating of the contents of the textbox:

```
<a ...href='map.html'...
```

This is taking precedence over the onclick event. You need to either change the link into a button and trigger the function as an onclick event or prevent the link from performing its normal function as other posters have noted with e.preventDefault().

Comment: But surely if I use e.preventDefault() then that means the user won't even be directed to the map?

Comment: hang on - are you passing the user to a new page and wanting the data from the old page to be visible on the new page? sorry - I missed that - you would need to use a query string (eg newPage.html?location=xyz) to pass the value to the new page, or sessionStorage / localStorage or session variables or cookies. or open a window and use window.opener to get the value to pass to the text box on the new page.

Comment: another way to do it - would be use Bootstrap and open a modal on the same page and not have to worry about passing variables between pages.

Comment: This all sounds a little out of my remit, therefore which is the simplest way of doing this and are you able to maybe to send any documentation?

Comment: new answer to help with that... :))